# Calculate the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} - \lambda\right) e^{-s}} ds$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Question**Find the integral:
>   $$
> \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} - \lambda\right) e^{-s}} ds,
> $$
>   here $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ is an arbitrary number.

**Sidenote**
In my eyes this integral seems to be fairly easy to solve, but I can't find it (and mathematica also can't solve it).

I do know that integrals can be solved using Complex Analysis but my memory of this approach is very vague so I can't decide whether this is applicable to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:$$ \frac{1}{c+be^{-s}}  = \frac{e^s}{ce^s+b}=\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{c}\log(ce^s+b)\right)'=}.$$

Then  with $c=\lambda$ and $b=\lambda-\frac{1}{\lambda}$ find
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} - \lambda\right) e^{-s}} ds,$$
Which obviously does not converges

Comment: No further elaboration required..
Thanks!

Comment: It amazes me that Mathematica couldn't figure this out

Comment: @HolyMonk don;t forget to checkmark for future readers

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 5 minutes, you were too fast!

Comment: I found it odd that the integral doesn't converge but there was a typo in my question, the $e^{-s}$ was supposed to  be $e^s$, but this integral is solved in exactly the same manner as the way you solved this integral.

Comment: @HolyMonk that is not a problem a slight change with $-c$ at the endpoint you get your results and in that situation it converges as well

Comment: Jep, I got it, thanks again

Comment: @GuyFonse : In general I actually have the integral:

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(\lambda e^{-s} + (\lambda^{1-k}-\lambda))^{1/(k-1)}}$

The one I posted here was this integral with $k = 2$, I just spent the last 2 hours trying to adapt your strategy to this integral but I can't figure it out, do you by any chance know how to tackle this one as well?

Comment: @HolyMonk may be you post some wherein another question. I dont see it right now

Comment: Okido, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Please note that integral doesn't converge. 
My approach without considering the interval of lamdda $]0,1[$

Answer is doesn't converge and indefinite integral gives
$\log((e^s -1)x^2 +1)/x $ as the answer.

Proceed yourself thereafter

Comment: He is not looking at the convergence. by the way you are right it does converge +1:)

Comment: @Guy Fsone Thanks

Comment: @ChenGuo: Thanks for your answer but the other one is even better than yours ;)!

Comment: @HolyMonk okay.