# Calculate the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(\lambda e^{-s} + (\lambda^{1-k} - \lambda))^{k-1}}ds$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Question**Find the integral:
>   $$
> \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(\lambda e^{-s} + (\lambda^{1-k} - \lambda))^{k-1}}ds
> $$
>   here $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $k \in\{2,3,\dots\}$ is are arbitrary.

**Sidenote**
This problem is strongly related to the one stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563369/calculate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac1-lambda-left-frac1-lambd/2563377?noredirect=1#comment5291440_2563377), as the linked problem is the same as this one but with $k = 2$. I thought I would be able to generalize the case $k =2$ to the general case but I don't really see it.

Comment: Substitution!!!

Comment: The integral in the link does not have $e^{-s}$ on the numerator.

Comment: Holy moly simple substitution!

Comment: I feel so dumb now :(! But thanks, as you may be able to tell: I don't solve many integrals anymore nowadays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:For $a\neq 1$ we have, $$\frac{e^{-s}}{(ce^{-s}+b)^a} =-\frac{1}{c(1-a)}\left( ce^{-s}+b)^{1-a}\right)'$$

take $a=k-1$. $c=\lambda$ and $b= \lambda^{k-1}-\lambda$
and

For a=1 we have

$$\frac{e^{-s}}{(ce^{-s}+b)} =-\frac{1}{c}\left(\log( ce^{-s}+b)\right)'$$

Comment: you are may lucky I have also added the other answer to your previous question. since you did a misprint